# Create custom table based input in FCITX

Tags: unicode, input-method, unicode-entry, fcitx

To be able to input common Unicode characters, I want to create my own input method.  I would like to use FCITX, because I am already using it for Sogou-pinyin.  I have tried to follow the guide [here](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/How_to_make_your_own_table-based_input_method) and managed to create an `mb` file and table (hopefully working) but not managed to use them.

How do I create my own table based input methon using FCITX? and what should I do to "install" my input method?

Here is my config file:

```
[CodeTable]
UniqueName=minasymb
Name=MinaSymboler
IconName=minasymb
File=minasymb.mb
AdjustOrder=AdjustFreq
Priority=11
UsePY=False
PYKey=z
AutoSend=-1
NoneMatchAutoSend=-1
AutoPhrase=True
SaveAutoPhrase=0
ExactMatch=False
PromptTableCode=False
Enabled=True
LangCode=xx_XX
```

and part of my table:

```
;fcitx 版本 0x03 码表文件
键码=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäöABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖ
码长=4
规避字符=;
拼音=@
拼音长度=12
[组词规则]
e2=p11+p12+p21+p22
e3=p11+p21+p31+p32
a4=p11+p21+p31+n11
[数据]
@kursivtB ℬ
@kursivtC 
@kursivtD 
@kursivtE ℰ
@kursivtF ℱ
@kursivtG 
@kursivtH ℋ
@kursivtI ℐ
@kursivtJ 
@kursivtK 
@kursivtL ℒ
@kursivtM ℳ
@kursivtN 
@kursivtO 
@ordo
```

I did not understand all the rows in the header, so I left them as in the guide liked to above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add Wubi98 table to fcitx on Fedora, hope it helps for other linux users:

1. install the fcitx-table module
2. copy table files (*.mb and *.conf) to /usr/share/fcitx/table

You can install fcitx-table-* (e.g. fcitx-table-chinese) to get some table files as samples in /usr/share/fcitx/table, then clone and modify conf files to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

According to the guide of the link:
How to make your own table-based input method
https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/How_to_make_your_own_table-based_input_method

Please try using code length as it specified in your *.conf , which is 4.
Most tables use lower alphabets only for their codes.

If you want to use @xxxxx codes, the length limitation is 12. But your code @xxxxx has to be followed the PinYin rule, http://input.foruto.com/cccl/cccl_article025.htm, which has only 37 phonetic symbols of vowels and consonants. I.e. xxxxx is a combination of codes of some phonetic symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest way to do this might be to take an existing table and then edit it down? (or add the characters to your sougou table)

To that end, I wonder if my answer might also answer your question:

[How to edit fcitx tables & fix broken inputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356441/how-to-edit-fcitx-tables-fix-broken-inputs/1357306#1357306)

It uses the `fcitx-tools`: `mb2txt` & `txt2mb`.